# Shopware6: Get width and height of thumbnail - from the generated file

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to add width and height attributes to our image tags in our templates.
Unfortunately, when using media.width and media.height, I get the width and height that is entered as the thumbnail size. And not the actual size of the image being used.

Example:
We generate a thumbnail with the size 1200 x 1200. But it's a horizontal image, so the size is actual 1200 x 700 px.
Now I would like to add width="1200" height="700" to our image tag, but I get 1200 x 1200.

Is there any way to get the actual size in the templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original resolution of an image is stored in the `metaData` property of the `media` entity. You'll have to calculate the thumbnail size aspect ratio from the resolution of the original image.

```html
{% set thumbnail = media.thumbnails.first %}
{% set oHeight = media.metaData.height %}
{% set oWidth = media.metaData.width %}
{% if oHeight > oWidth %}
    {% set ratio = thumbnail.height / oHeight %}
{% else %}
    {% set ratio = thumbnail.width / oWidth %}
{% endif %}
{% set height = oHeight * ratio %}
{% set width = oWidth * ratio %}
<img src="{{ thumbnail.url }}"
     height="{{ height|round }}"
     width="{{ width|round }}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was so helpful! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate them by metadata :-( but, why do you need these attributes? - because of Google? Ignore it, it is nonsense, because the images are not static sized. Keyword: responsive

Here comes a useful alternative:
Just serve aspect-ratio: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/

You can check it f.e. In following plugin: https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshLazySizes

Answer (score 1):

It may not matter much at all for SEO, but it does for UX. E.g. Avoiding Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS), and as such it may have more of an indirect influence. But this **really should be fixed** so users don't accidentally click things because the elements on the page are shifting around doing page load.

Here is what I did.

At the bottom, inside `src/Resources/views/storefront/utilities/thumbnail.html.twig`, add something like this:

```
<img {% if load %}src="{{ def_image }}" {% else %}data-src="{{ media|sw_encode_media_url }}" {% endif %}
    {% if load %}
      height="{{ thumbnails|first.height }}"
      width="{{ thumbnails|first.width }}"
    {% endif %}

    {% if media.thumbnails|length > 0 %}
        {% if load %}srcset="{{ srcsetValue }}" {% else %}data-srcset="{{ srcsetValue }}" {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for key, value in attributes %}{% if value != '' %} {{ key }}="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% endfor %}
 />
```

Note. I only added this part:

```
{% if load %}
  height="{{ thumbnails|first.height }}"
  width="{{ thumbnails|first.width }}"
{% endif %}
```

It makes sure to only add `width` and `height` when the src attribute is used. You will also need to do this separately for the site logo, but for that I think you may need to make a Twig extension and use PHP's `getimagesize`, because I have not been able to find the dimensions stored anywhere readily available from `.twig`.

The site logo is located in: `src/Resources/views/storefront/layout/header/logo.html.twig`

Since the images are responsive, this will not work without defining the aspect ratio of the images in your CSS. You need something like this:

```
.product-image-wrapper img, .cms-image-container.is-stretch img, .product-slider-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height);
}
```

The exact images you need to apply the CSS on may vary depending on theme. Etc. You just gotta inspect each `<img>` element with broken aspect ratio and add it to the CSS.

I recommend you do all this from your child theme so changes are not overwritten when you update.